# jQuery plugin development preserve element original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a jQuery plugin to create modal windows, so, now, I want to restore element original state after hide it.

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

---- update ---

Sorry,

I want to store element html in some place when show it, then put the stored data back when hide it.

This is my plugin:

```
(function ($) { // v2ui_modal
    var methods = {
        show: function (options) {
            var _this = this;

            var defaults = {
                showOverlay: true,
                persistentContent: true
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            if (!_this.attr('id')) {
                _this.attr('id', 'v2ui-id_' + Math.random().toString().replace('.', ''));
            }

            if (options.showOverlay) {
                $('<div />', { // overlay
                    id: 'v2-ui-plugin-modal-overlay-' + this.attr('id'),
                    css: {
                        zIndex: ($.topZIndex() + 1),
                        display: 'none',
                        position: 'fixed',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0
                    }
                }).addClass('v2-ui').addClass('plugin').addClass('overlay').appendTo('body');
            };

            _this.css({
                zIndex: ($.topZIndex() + 2),
                position: 'fixed'
            });

            _this.center();

            $('#v2-ui-plugin-modal-overlay-' + _this.attr('id')).fadeIn(function () {
                _this.fadeIn();
            });
        },

        hide: function () {
            var _this = this;

            _this.fadeOut();

            $('#v2-ui-plugin-modal-overlay-' + _this.attr('id')).fadeOut(function () {
                $('#v2-ui-plugin-modal-overlay-' + _this.attr('id')).remove();
                if ((_this.attr('id')).substr(0, 8) == 'v2ui-id_') {
                    _this.removeAttr('id');
                };
            });
        }
    };

    jQuery.fn.v2ui_modal = function (methodOrOptions) {
        if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
            methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
            methods.show.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Too vague. Post some code. What have you tried?

Comment: From the information we've got so far, I'm going for: `$(".yourElement").show();`

Comment: How can we possibly help you with so few information...

Comment: I tryed to create an array to store element original html, but, when I call 'hide' method, the array is empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [`jQuery.detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

But I am having a hard time understanding your problem fully, so I apologize if my answer does not fit your question.